# SQL: use SELECT to INSERT data into table with extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I have a table `Table1` with 59 columns. `Table2` is a copy of `Table1` with one extra column, `COLUMN 60` at the end. Hence `table2` has 60 columns.

I am trying to copy the values from `table1` to `table2` and set value of the extra column in `table2` to "value"

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO Table2
   SELECT * FROM Table1, 'value' AS 'COLUMN 60'
```

How can I do this? Using the code above give me an error:

> *An explicit value for the identity column in table 'TableLocation' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT
>   is ON.*

I do not want to specify column names because there are too many of those.

Comment: If you cannot use all columns (`SELECT *`) because one of the columns is an `IDENTITY` column - then you **must** specify **all** columns that you want to insert into and that you want to select from  `table1` .... (it's better anyway to **always** explicitly specify which columns you want to insert and select!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table2 ON

INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT *, 'value' AS 'COLUMN 60' FROM Table1

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table2 OFF
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SELECT *, 'value' FROM dbo.Table1 ....` ?? You want to select an additional **column** - not from an additional table ....

Comment: @marc_s - I cut and paste from the OP's question, however, having reviewed I agree - have edited.

Answer (score 3):

You know that you can just drag the column names from SSMS right? Navigate to the table and then drag the columns folder into the query window, it will list all the columns for you

Now if you want to preserve the identity values then use

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table2 ON

--INSERT HERE
-- make sure to list all the columns, it is required

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Table2 OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to be done in one statement?

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT * FROM Table1

ALTER TABLE Table2
ADD Column60 varchar
```

Comment: I do not want to recreate the whole table2 because I will lost the value in the extra column already present

Comment: ahh, i didn't realize you were looking to append to existing data in table2.  sorry.